# How would you create an expression parser in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, interpreted-language

I am just curious. Like in interpreted languages or even statement calculators how do people convert the strings given by input or files to actual expressions? e.g **"Enter Calculation: "** and you write **"2*7/4"** which is a string. How does the program convert the string into an actual expression? It is easy to convert a string to an int but how do you convert *operators* like  **+** , **-** , **/**, etc.? I understand that these kind of things are usually implemented in **C/C++** but is it possible to make such a thing in a high-level language like **C#**? And If yes then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's [an article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/GenExpParser.aspx) you might check out. There are also tools like [Flee](http://flee.codeplex.com/). Or yet [another technique](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/evalcscode.aspx) which allows you to evaluate C# expressions using a CodeDom provider.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be achieved using expression trees, which is how LINQ is implemented.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Google "parse tree". One can be written in any Turing-complete language.